# How would I add in the function to print percent for the user's score along with the correct answer for the user?

Tags: python, python-2.7

It just prints the incorrect questions as of right now and I have no clue as to how I can make it print the user's percent as well?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def main():
correctAnswers = ['B', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'A']
# questionNumber = ['1′,'2′,'3′,'4′,'5′,'6′,'7′,'8′,'9′,'10']

studentInput = raw_input('Enter the Answers in one line: ')
studentInput = studentInput.split(' ')
studentAnswerList = studentInput
print studentAnswerList

correct = 0
incorrect = 0
incorrectAnswers = [0] * 10
for count in range(10):
    if studentAnswerList[count] == correctAnswers[count]:
        correct += 1
    elif studentAnswerList[count] != correctAnswers[count]:
        incorrect += 1
        incorrectAnswers[count] = studentAnswerList[count]
print studentAnswerList
print correctAnswers

# if statement to compare answers and indicate if student passed or failed
if correct >= 5:
    print 'Passed ', correct
else:
    print 'Failed ', incorrect
print incorrectAnswers

main()
```

Comment: Where would I put that code in?

Comment: instead of `range(10)`

Comment: it shows me syntax error

Comment: the first question will match the `correctAnswers[0]` index, is that wanted ? the test looks ok if we input the right answers

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code adding a little comparation before start the program and adding the percentage too. It seems it's what you want.

```
from __future__ import division
def main():
    correctAnswers = ['B', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'A']

    studentInput = raw_input('Enter the Answers in one line: ')
    studentInput = studentInput.split(' ')
    studentAnswerList = studentInput
    print studentAnswerList

    correct = 0
    incorrect = 0
    incorrectAnswers = [0] * 10
    percentage = 0.0

    if len(studentAnswerList) == len(correctAnswers):
        for count in range(10):
            if studentAnswerList[count] == correctAnswers[count]:
                correct += 1
            elif studentAnswerList[count] != correctAnswers[count]:
                incorrect += 1
                incorrectAnswers[count] = studentAnswerList[count]

        if correct > 0:
            percentage = (incorrect / len(correctAnswers))*100

        # if statement to compare answers and indicate if student passed or failed
        if correct >= 5:
            print 'Passed ', correct
        else:
            print 'Failed ', incorrect

        print 'You have failed the ' + str(percentage) + '% questions'
    else:
        print 'You should answer to ' + str(len(correctAnswers)) + ' questions'

main()
```